# FIX Xiaomi redmi series phones stuck in bootloader, system update rom for rooted phone

Tags: android, bootloader, xiaomi

I've been messing around with my phone(redmi note 8t) in the past few days, installed root, tried to install Pixel Experience OS(which didn't work at all), got stuck in a bootloop with Pixel Experience OS like 7 times, tried to install default rom again, didn't work because I couldn't mount /data folder in twrp, so I came up with a solution. In this txt file, I assume you've already tried rooting your phone or flashing a new rom onto it, so you should be familiar with twrp.img files, etc.
You'll need an sd card for this(if the ROM you're trying to flash is like 2 gigs than you can get one with 4GB capacity, but I recommend one with 8GB), as well as a PC with minimal adb and fastboot folder on it.
If you want to root your device right after fixing the bootloader with default rom, or flashing new rom, simply just follow along after "DONE!!!"
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xE_YJY2Mdar0bw5D83FI7RfsVzAz_j-d?usp=sharing
Read the readme.txt
I hope you find this useful, good luck!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, because it is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reflash a recovery, but for that you have to use a lineageOS recovery which you can download from lineageOS download section for your device. You can also try to flash orangefox recovery.

Actually I faced this issue and then afterwards I solved this problem in the same way.

Good luck !